# Error that's related to working directory when using plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, directory, plotly

Im trying to use the ggplotly function on a certain plot, and i get a strange error that's related to the working directory.

here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#constructing a data frame
data = data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-08-21"),as.Date("2021-08-30"), "day"),
                 first = rnorm(1:10),
                 second = rnorm(1:10),
                 third = rnorm(1:10)) 
data
#turning the data to long format
data_long <- data %>% 
  gather(key = "index", value = "value", -date)

#graphing
plot <- data_long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=value, color=index))+
  labs(x="", y="value")+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~index)
plot

ggplotly(plot)
```

Everything is running well except for the ggplotly command. When i run it i get the following error:

```
Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory
```

I don't understand the connection between the command and the error message, since i haven't mean to change the directory at all.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please make a reproducible example so others can help. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()` and use the reprex-package.

Comment: Is the problem with the code or your RDE (eg. RStudio)?  Let's assume you do have `data_long` setup in your environment (and you can see it with, for example `View(data_long)`).  Then, run each of your lines of code *in the console* directly, one right after another.  First set `plot <- ...`, then check via `plot`, then check via `ggplotly(plot)`.  If you still get the error message, then it could be the code... but seems like this might be either due to some other code outside of what you've shared or possibly a setting in your desktop environement.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I have edited my post and replaced the original code with a reproducible example (@Tung @mnist)
I've tried to run in the console directly, one right after another. Still the same error (@chemdork123).

Thanks again

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Clear your R session and run the code as you posted it here. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: OP, seems it's your installation of R and possibly something related to the way your libraries are loaded.  Try a new session and running it.  Try updating the packages you're using (just `install.packages(...)` again works).  Not sure how else we will be able to help if we cannot reproduce the error here.